# MySQL - designating an image to a record

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with two tables:

- `animals`
- `animal_images`

`animals` looks like this, `animal_id` is its primary key, it auto-increments, and it serves as a reference key for the other table `animal_images`:

```
    +-----------+-------------+
    | animal_id | animal_name |
    +-----------+-------------+
    |         1 | cat         |
    |         2 | dog         |
    |         3 | lizard      |
    +-----------+-------------+
```

`animal_images` looks like this, `animal_img_id` is its primary key and it auto_increments. `animal_id` is indexed as a foreign key:

```
    +---------------+-----------+-------------+
    | animal_img_id | animal_id |  img_file   |
    +---------------+-----------+-------------+
    |             1 |         1 | cat1.jpg    |
    |             2 |         1 | cat2.jpg    |
    |             3 |         1 | cat3.jpg    |
    |             4 |         2 | dog1.jpg    |
    |             5 |         2 | dog2.jpg    |
    |             6 |         3 | lizard1.jpg |
    |             7 |         3 | lizard2.jpg |
    +---------------+-----------+-------------+
```

What I want to do is to specify that one of the images in `animal_images` is the primary image for a certain animal.

So for example `cat1.jpg` is the primary image for `cat` and once it has been designated, it's not possible to designate `cat2.jpg` or `cat3.jpg` as a primary image for `cat`.

And just to clarify:

- dog or lizard images should never be eligible for `cat`
- `cat` could have zero images designated to it

What would be the best way to do this?  Can I set up relationships and constraints in the database to do this? Or is this something that I will just have to check when inserting, updating, and deleting?

Comment: Add another column to the animal table referencing the image that you want to be the primary image?  Then add a foreign key constraint covering both the animal_id and the image_id.

Comment: You get into a chicken and egg situation though if both tables have foreign key constraints on each other, the animal table relying on the aminaml_img_id and the images table relying on the animal_id.  To create one the other needs to already be created.  And also, how do you allow for no image to be set as a primary image?

Comment: The foreign key I suggested already accomplishes that. Make the key be Both columns not just the image_id...  (Will tell you that you also need a unique constraint on the combination of those two columns in the image table.)

Comment: There is no chicken and egg. A foreign key is allowed to be null.

Comment: Using both the animal_id and the image_id in one foreign key means that it will be impossible to link a cat image to a non-cat animal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments.

The structure below means that:

- An animal can only ever have one or zero "default" images
- Any default image must already be associated with that animal

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed7ee7/1

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
  animal_id                INT,
  animal_name              VARCHAR(32),
  default_animal_image_id  INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (animal_id)
);

CREATE TABLE animal_images (
  animal_image_id          INT,
  animal_id                INT,
  image_file               VARCHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (animal_image_id)
);

   ALTER TABLE animal_images
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_animal_images__animal_id
   FOREIGN KEY (animal_id)
    REFERENCES animals(animal_id);

   ALTER TABLE animal_images
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_animal_images
       UNIQUE (animal_id, animal_image_id);

   ALTER TABLE animals
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_animals__default_animal_image
   FOREIGN KEY (animal_id, default_animal_image_id)
    REFERENCES animal_images(animal_id, animal_image_id);

INSERT INTO animals VALUES (1, 'cat',    NULL);
INSERT INTO animals VALUES (2, 'dog',    NULL);
INSERT INTO animals VALUES (3, 'lizard', NULL);

INSERT INTO animal_images VALUES (1, 1, 'cat1.jpg');
INSERT INTO animal_images VALUES (2, 1, 'cat2.jpg');
INSERT INTO animal_images VALUES (3, 1, 'cat3.jpg');
INSERT INTO animal_images VALUES (4, 2, 'dog1.jpg');
INSERT INTO animal_images VALUES (5, 2, 'dog2.jpg');
INSERT INTO animal_images VALUES (6, 3, 'lizard1.jpg');
INSERT INTO animal_images VALUES (7, 3, 'lizard2.jpg');

UPDATE animals SET default_animal_image_id = 1 WHERE animal_id = 1;
UPDATE animals SET default_animal_image_id = 4 WHERE animal_id = 2;
UPDATE animals SET default_animal_image_id = 6 WHERE animal_id = 3;
```

Comment: Thx @MatBailie. Didn't know I could have `animals.animal_image_id` set to `NULL`. I modified the code to make animals.animal_id auto increment. Then I run `INSERT INTO animals (animal_id, animal_name, default_animal_image_id) VALUES ('', 'horse', NULL)`, and that is successful, but gives a warning, `Warning: 1366: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'animal_id' at row 1.` Should I be concerned about this warning or ignore it since I am successfully executing my query?

Comment: If you're using auto increment, don't specify the animal_id column, or a value for it.

Comment: `INSERT INTO animals (animal_name, default_animal_image_id) VALUES ('horse', NULL)`. Adding NULL as the default for the image means you can remove that from the insert statement too.

Comment: it's users like you that make StackOverflow so amazing. Thank you for guiding me through this problem.